# duda con modulos y directivas angularjs

Tags: angularjs

tengo el siguiente codigo:

> 1.- por que usar directivas?, en este caso no seria suficiente usar controller?
>
> 2.- el controller siempre lleva una funcion con scope?

```js
(function() {

  var modulo=angular.module('tnt.ui.components', []);
  modulo.directive('userInfo', [function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      template:'Nombre: {{user.name}}, email: <a href="mailto:{{user.email}}">{{user.email}}</a>'
    };
  }]);
  
  
  
 
  modulo.controller('DemoDirectivesCtrl', function($scope){
      $scope.user = {
        name: 'Jose',
        email: 'jmsanchez@autentia.com'
      };
  });

}());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    
<div ng-app="tnt.ui.components" ng-controller="DemoDirectivesCtrl">
    <user-info />
</div>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: hubman, recuerda que Stackoverflow en español funciona solo si haces preguntas específicas y concretas. Debes hacer una sola pregunta en cada publicación. Asegúrate que tus preguntas no estén sujetas a opiniones.

Comment: @toledano el flujo de ejecucion para cada usuario varia?

Comment: Por favor, edita tu pregunta agregando todas las aclaraciones que consideres pertinentes, de modo que pueda proponer la pregunta para apertura.

Comment: @toledano ya lo edite la pregunta

Comment: Pero agrega algunos detallas, ¿tienes algún error que puedas compartir, cuál es el resultado esperado? La idea es incluir un __[mcve]__.

Answer (score 1):

Con *module* defines una aplicación, es decir que cobijado por este módulo estará toda la magia que AngularJS le pueda proporcionar a tu HTML.

Las directivas se pueden entender como atributos que puedes añadir a tus etiquetas HTML y que te permiten extender la funcionalidad del bloque de código como *snippets*.

Con *controller* agregas toda la lógica a todos los elementos que definas en el resto de tu aplicación.

La variable *scope* sirve de pegamento entre tu vista y tu controlador.

Te recomiendo que visites la [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/default.asp) y veas en mayor detalle cada uno de los puntos sobre los que tienes duda